# CORS issue using Windows Authentication in AngularJS/WebApi application - only works in IE

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors, windows-authentication

I have an intranet application with an AngularJS front end and an ASP.NET Web API back end and they are separate web applications running on IIS on the same server. The reason the Web API isn't in the same project with the UI project is because it will be shared with other intranet applications.

I need to provide some security features. I need to know who each user is and limit what can be done based on who that user is and what role (Windows group) the user belongs to. I've enabled Windows Authentication in both applications and I've done this by putting the following in the web.config of both parts:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

I haven't done anything yet with the authorization because I've noticed that while I can browse the site with either Chrome or Internet Explorer, I cannot access the Web API project unless I use IE. In Chrome, I ran the developer tools and I see this:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62415/api/CustomerGroups. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50900' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I've enabled CORS in my code but it doesn't seem to make a difference when using Chrome. I can however access the API URL and get data back.

I've done some research and I've added a Startup class in my Web API project as such:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApi.Startup))]
namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

I did have this code in my Global.asax.cs but apparently it isn't needed since I'm using the Startup class and it doesn't make a difference whether it is there or not:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Context.Request.Path.Contains("api/") || Context.Request.Path.Contains("odata/")) && Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do to allow this to work with browsers other IE?

I know the rest of the security stuff is going to be complicated but I need to get over this hurdle first.

Comment: I pushed my sites to QA and found that Chrome works there. I think this has something to do with running on localhost for development.  In QA, the sites are running as subdomains of the same domain and the CORS stuff isn't needed there. Perhaps I need to make some entries in my hosts file to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

3 links that might help you - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2